# jQuery Mobile video flicker after transition

Tags: jquery, video, mobile, flicker

I'm making a small app for the iPad using jquery mobile and phonegap.  The page transitions are nice and things seem to work well.  But when I add a video (an HTML5 video tag) to one of the pages everything mostly works fine still except once in a while after a page transition away from the page with the video it will flicker the video box.  Only happens about 30% of the time.  Seems kind of random.  So anytime I transition away from my video page it will flicker the video on the next page for a split second.  its really annoying.  Doesn't happen in the simulator either.

Does anyone know how to stop it?  I've tried everything including adding -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; to my .ui-page class in the jquery mobile CSS.  Nothing seems to stop it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Found some info here; https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/455

old bug, some small fixes in the thread, but not released yet.

Seems to be in what order you set the "webkit-backface-visibility" , first i tried in seperate .css file and load it early.  Some flicker gone and some still left.

Then I added below code after everything at the very end of  tag and video/transitions not flickring anymore on iphone and ipad.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
    /* patch for jquerymobile page flicker */
    .ui-page {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    } 
</style>
</head>
```